# how to upgrade java app to Openshift v3

Tags: java, git, github, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I'm trying to migrate a java app that runs on Wildfly from Openshift Online v2 to Openshift Online v3 and having difficulties. I go through the steps here

https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/migrating_applications/web_framework_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-web-framework-applications-jboss-as

and get to

"4. Use the the oc command to launch a new Wildfly application from the builder image and source code:

```
$ oc new-app https://github.com/<github-id>/<repo-name>.git
 --image-stream=”openshift/wildfly:10.0" --name=<app-name> -e
 <ENV_VAR_NAME>=<env_var_value>"
```

I get the error "error: No language matched the source repository"

1) How does Openshift even know what my account is?

2) Why doesn't it know what to do with my .war files?

I tried adding a Wildfly cartridge to my account, thinking whether I understand how or not, somehow the oc command knows which account is mine, and I need a Wildfly cartridge before it can recognize a .war file.

I get to the part where it asks me for my Git repository URL and it gives me the message:

" Please enter a valid name.

A valid name is applied to all generated resources. It is an alphanumeric (a-z, and 0-9) string with a maximum length of 24 characters, where the first character is a letter (a-z), and the '-' character is allowed anywhere except the first or last character."

How is that possible? "https://github.com//.git" is already 24 characters; "https://github.com/github-id/repo-name.git" is going to be too long no matter what my github id is or my repository name is.

Comment: For a Wildfly application, try working through the example in the free eBook for OpenShift. https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

Comment: I tried downloading the ebook, it won't open in MS word. Is it supposed to?

Comment: It is a PDF file so no. Use Acrobat Reader.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question about how do I put a URL for my repository when the maximum length of the URL is 24 characters.

Answer (score 0):

So, working through each of your issues here

1. The migration guides assume that you have already logged in to `oc` and created your projects. If you haven't, you can do so as follows

   `oc login api.starter-<region>.openshift.com`

   `oc new-project <project-name>`

   Where  matches the URL for the cluster that you've signed up for, and  can be any name that hasn't already been taken on that cluster (I've found it's usually easiest to my username, as it's rarely already taken). By logging in and creating your project (if you already have 1 project, then the `oc login` will use that project by default and you can skip `oc new-project`), this is how OpenShift will know what account to use.
2. `oc new-app` uses some key files in your git repo to determine what language to deploy, you can find this list of files used for language detection in the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html#language-detection). So for your application, you need to be sure to include a *pom.xml* file. You can find an example of a git repository for Wildfly [here](https://github.com/gshipley/book-helloworld). That should help you in deploying your application.
3. When using `--name`, you need to actually specify an application name, instead of using the default provided `<app-name>`. The command is complaining that `<` and `>` are not valid characters to use, and is **not** referring to your git repo URL being too long.

Comment: 123456789012345678901234 that's 24 characters

Comment: Yes it is, the 24 character limit is NOT referring to the git repo URL.

Comment: Sorry that comment yesterday was not complete. I did substitute a name for <app-name>, I was just repeating the instructions provided verbatim in my question. I had no funny characters in the name, it was all alpha numeric. That gave me the "error: No language matched the source repository" error when I tried to run it in the command window. So I thought I needed to do something on the openshift website before I ran that command. I tried to add a java to my project on the openshift website and that was where it complained about the length of my github url.

Comment: Could you please provide the full command that you are trying?

Comment: oc new-app https://github.com/iheitsch/practiceMath.git --image-stream="openshift/wildfly:10.0" --name=practiceMath

Comment: looking through your previous answer, you say I need a pom.xml file. That is for use with Maven, correct? I didn't use Maven with Openshift Online v2. Is it a requirement with v3?

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, so I can't test, but have you tried `--name=practicemath` in lower case?

Comment: yes, same error. I also added the pom.xml file and edited it substituting "practiceMath" for "SampleApp". Tried both camelCase and lower case

Comment: The example of a git repository that you gave earlier uses uncompressed java files, not .war files. Is that the problem, should I put uncompressed source code in my repository rather than a .war file?

Answer (score 0):

so to partially answer my question,

```
    oc new-app https://github.com/<github-id>/<repo-name>.git
    --image-stream=”openshift/wildfly:10.0"
```

should not have quotes around openshift/wildfly:10.0

I tried this, and skipped the --name option and it completed without any error message.
That said, it produces nothing that displays as a webpage.

Back to trying to deploy from openshift's webpage:

the error I was getting:
" Please enter a valid name.

A valid name is applied to all generated resources. It is an alphanumeric (a-z, and 0-9) string with a maximum length of 24 characters, where the first character is a letter (a-z), and the '-' character is allowed anywhere except the first or last character."

was referring to the first box I filled out, not the github url. I don't recall what I put there, but I probably had an uppercase letter that was causing the error.

It took a long time to build an deploy and it looked like it had finished when it had not, but eventually I was able to click on the url for my website and it displayed my index page. I'm now having issues adding anything beyond the index page